# What model to use for relative comparison between 3 figures?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, machine-learning-model, embeddings

I am working on a problem where I am given three images of different dishes `(A,B,C)` and the task is to figure out if figure `B` or figure `C` is closest to figure `A` (in terms of taste). I have a training set with ordered images `(A,P,N)` where `P` (positive) is closest to `A` (anchor) and `N` (negative). Now I figured that I somehow need to come up with an embedding that is representative of the taste, and then use a metric `d(.,.)` that meaningfully compares the dishes. Ideally `d(embedding(A),embedding(B)) < d(embedding(A),embedding(C))` implies that dish `A` is closer in taste to dish `B` than it is to dish `C`.

Now I did some research and found the so-called TripletLoss, which seems to tackle a very similar problem. A nice blog post by Olivier Moindrot can be found [here](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) on the topic, and it includes the figure below.

[image: https://github.com/omoindrot/tensorflow-triplet-loss]

The problem is that contrary to the implementations I found online, my dataset is not labelled. I simply have ordered triplets from which I need to extract information for the right embedding. The dishes in my dataset are all unique, and cannot be grouped meaningfully into discrete classes. Yet, I still want to come up with something like a metric that is able to compare the dishes.

My question: Am I going in the right direction? Are there any models that would suit my problem better? My knowledge of ML/NNs is still somewhat limited so any suggestion into the right direction is appreciated!